# How to use pg_dump/pg_restore to update database?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pg-restore

Say I have `db0` on the local machine and `db1` on a remote server. I just want to keep `db1` up-to-date with `db0`.

Say I added few (thousands) rows to `my_table` in `db0` and now I want to insert it to `my_table` in `db1`.

All the recipes and docs about pg_dump/pg_restore say about full restoration of the table, however, I don't need (and don't want) to drop and to restore `my_table` from scratch.

Is there any clear and simple way to make a file, `scp` it to the server and just `pg_restore` from it?

Just two commands: for pg_dump and for pg_restore. Because I'm looking through docs and walkthroughs for about two hours getting new errors and becoming confused more and more.

Comment: It sounds like pg_dump and pg_restore aren't really what you should be using... to my knowledge they're really more for fully restoring databases / tables not just inserting 
 specific records.  I'd be interested in the solution, I'm thinking some kind of temp table creation from the db0 file (maybe with COPY?), then INSERT FROM SELECT on the temp table where records don't match the target table.  But there's probably some postgres magic that would be a little more simple.

Comment: COPY sometimes goes broken on newlines (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38315121/solving-error-literal-newline-found-in-data-in-postgres), that's why I wanted to stick to pg_restore...

Comment: @zyd If you're intrested in a solution - please, vote up the question to make it more noticeable for pg wizards

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a statement like `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` or `MERGE` (which will probably come in v12), but that requires that you have access to both tables at the same time.

So you either have to use a foreign table or dump/restore the table into a different table in the destination database.

Comment: I'm using this recipe: https://carlosbecker.com/posts/dump-postgres-table-inserts/ But it is not easy on thousands records...

Comment: Yes, but what about duplicates?

Comment: Very good question! I'm editing the output file to remove INSERTs for duplicates.